# MySQL 5.7 max_connections reset after reboot

Tags: mysql, percona

We have a set of PXC clusters, each with slaves that we are using for reads. The slaves are running percona server 5.7 with " max_connections" and "max_user_connections" set to 4000 and 4050 respectively. But every time we reboot our slaves, these values are automatically reset to the default values out of the box causing a lot of performance issues. Is this a bug, or are we missing something in our config?

Below is our config file (SSD):

```
#
# Default values.
[mysqld_safe]
flush_caches
numa_interleave
#
#
[mysqld]
back_log = 65535
binlog_format = ROW
character_set_server = utf8
collation_server = utf8_general_ci
#core_file
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
enforce-gtid-consistency = 1
expand_fast_index_creation = 1
expire_logs_days = 2
gtid_mode = ON
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 64
innodb_buffer_pool_populate = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 67G #77G
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:64M;ibdata2:64M:autoextend
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_io_capacity = 20000
innodb_large_prefix
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 1
#innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_print_all_deadlocks = 1
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_stats_on_metadata = FALSE
innodb_support_xa = FALSE
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
log-bin = mysqld-bin
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
log-slave-updates
long_query_time = 1
master_info_repository = TABLE
max_allowed_packet = 64M
max_connect_errors = 4294967295
max_connections = 4000
max_user_connections = 4050
min_examined_row_limit = 1000
port = 3306
read-only = 1
relay_log_info_repository = TABLE
relay-log-recovery = TRUE
skip-name-resolve
slave_parallel_workers = 8
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_timestamp_always = 1
table_open_cache = 4096
thread_cache = 1024
tmpdir = /srv/tmp
transaction_isolation = REPEATABLE-READ
updatable_views_with_limit = 0
user = mysql
wait_timeout = 60
userstat
#innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=1
#innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=1
#skip_slave_start
#
##for grafana dashboard monitoring
#query_response_time_stats = on
userstat = 1
server-id = 1019244
```

Comment: Could percona change them after boot?   Apart from that, ever heard of "connection pooling" ?

Comment: How are you managing to SET GLOBAL all these variables, every reboot?  When you have 64 innodb_buffer_pool_instances you need to adjust down to 100  innodb_lru_scan_depth.  The workload of lru_scan_depth is determined by  instances * lru_scan_depth, every SECOND.  See refman for lru_scan_depth  v 5.7.  Have you tried 8 innodb_buffer_pool_instances?  Even at 8 IBPI the scan depth should be set to 128, not 1024 per the refman.

Comment: Please post results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "%capacity%";  Thanks

Comment: Hi Wilson You command shows these results: Variable_name: innodb_io_capacity = 20000, Variable_name: innodb_io_capacity_max = 40000

Comment: With v5.7, we discovered that using innodb_buffer_pool_instances (upto 64) value different from the Innodb_buffer_pool_size will cause issues with MySQL. So if innodb_buffer_pool_size is 32GB, then innodb_buffer_pool_instances should have the value of 32 and so on and so forth.

Comment: @thegeorgia Your first response confirms that when only innodb_io_capacity is requested, instance startup does apply the *2 to innodb_io_capacity_max which confirms a tip I found somewhere.   For innodb_buffer_pool_instances, just make them the same in your .ini and don't count on the 64 to auto calculate your need, easy to implement and no confusion when someone is looking at your .ini.  Right?

Comment: @thegeorgia Actually, innodb_buffer_pool_instances=nn of G of innodb_buffer_pool_size.  What is your innodb_lru_scan_depth set to?
And what is your innodb_page_cleaners set to?

Comment: innodb_lru_scan_depth = 1024, and innodb_page_cleaners is empty.

Comment: @ Wilson Hauck, just make innodb_buffer_pool_instances the same to what?

Answer (score 0):

Goto /etc/my.cnf and set
max_connections=1000
Then restart mysql